# looking for a verb to use with `benefit`, to describe something like benefit is lost/damaged

Tags: word-choice, verbs

I'm looking for a verb to use  want to describe something like benefit is *lost / damaged*.

> If you use this technology, your work will be finished earlier. But if you are lazy, the benefits due to this technology will be *damaged / lost*.

I know *damaged / lost* is not proper verbs, so what verbs should I use to replace it?

Comment: To lose the benefits works - if your are lazy, you will lose the benefits

Comment: lose is 100%， is there a word corresponding to `damage`?

Comment: "... you will lose *some* of the benefits".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

curtailed, lost, ruined, squandered, nullified, wasted, rendered ineffective...

Answer (score 2):

Benefits are very much lost if the beneficiary does not taken advantage, so lost/lose is the right word choice.

No one would appreciate you suggesting that they might be lazy. The more subtle wording would be,

> You will save time and lower your costs by using this technology. However, should you not take full advantage of the technology, you will lose (some of) these benefits.